# how to use normal websocket events in a meteor app?

Tags: meteor, websocket, ddp

I'm working on a multiplayer game that sends a lot of data over sockets, and using the meteor stack.

What is the best way to hook into DDP to send/receive events, and act on them yourself?
or should i try and mix normal websocket events in?

Checking [the DDP spec here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/DDP.md) RPC is supported from client to server, but I don't see the other way around. From server to client is Added/Updated/Removed collections type messages. I guess i could just use one of these, but is there a lower level for sending your own message types?
eg If I want to send different types of messages ("playerMove") from the server to the clients, what might be a way to do that?

If I could pub/sub to a channel, and send my own msgs back and forth that get mapped to client events / methods that would save more infra/plumbing in the app.

Pointers/code snippets appreciated!

reference:
- [DDP spec](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/DDP.md)
- [Android DDP client](https://github.com/kenyee/android-ddp-client)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the streams package originally from arunoda could be useful.  Looks like a 0.9 compatible fork is up here: https://atmospherejs.com/lepozepo/streams